# How can I set the fill aesthetic using a character vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

This is a pretty straightforward question, I just can't figure out the correct syntax. I'm making several bar plots based on an element (column) of my dataframe:

```
ggplot(df) +
geom_col(aes(x=factor(Cluster), y=1, fill=Fe)) +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", direction = 1) +
labs(fill="Fe")
```

The part that changes is the fill Element (e.g., Fe, Ca, Si, Ti). I'm making plots for several dataframes, but each plot will use the same element. Instead of going through and changing every ggplot code, I'd like to set a character vector first so that everything uses the same element, something like:

```
ClusterElement <- "Fe"
ggplot(df) +
geom_col(aes(x=factor(Cluster), y=1, fill=ClusterElement)) +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", direction = 1) +
labs(fill=paste0(ClusterElement))
```

The `labs()` code works but the `fill=ClusterElement` gives an error that a "Discrete value was applied to a continuous scale". The values for each element are continuous and range between 0 and 1.

How can I properly call the ClusterElement into the fill aesthetic? I have also tried `fill=colnames() %in% ClusterElement`, `fill=matches(ClusterElement)`, and `fill=df %>% select(ClusterElement)`. I know that last one doesn't make much sense but I thought I'd give it a try.

I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this and I'm grateful to anyone who takes the time to provide it to me!

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Several options. Personally I'm used to the .data pronoun, i.e. try `fill=.data[[ClusterElement]]`

Comment: I knew there was a simple option. Thanks!